# Comparing $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ for independent random variables with values in an abelian locally compact group

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, haar-measure

Let $G$ be an abelian locally (separable?) compact group with Haar measure $\mu$. Inspired by the interesting proof of [A sum of two binomial random variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357655/a-sum-of-two-binomial-random-variables) :
Let $X$ and $Y$ be $G$-valued independent random variables with $\mu$-density $f_X$ resp. $f_Y$. Let $f_{X \pm Y}$ be the $\mu$-density of $X \pm Y$. Is it always true that
$$\int f_{X-Y}^2 d\mu = \int f_{X+Y}^2 d\mu \ ?$$
This holds true for $G = \mathbb{Z}$ (here both integrals are finite)
.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes. Indeed, let $dx:=\mu(dx)$ for brevity. We have 
\begin{align}
I_{X,Y}&:=\iiint f_X(x'+y'-y)f_Y(y)f_Y(y')f_X(x')dx'\,dy\,dy' \\ 
&=\iint f_{X+Y}(x'+y')f_Y(y')f_X(x')dx'\,dy' \\ 
&=\iint f_{X+Y}(t)f_Y(t-x')f_X(x')dt\,dx' \\ 
&=\int f_{X+Y}(t)^2dt. 
\end{align}
Also,
\begin{align}
I_{X,Y}&=\iiint f_X(x'-u'+u)f_Y(-u)f_Y(-u')f_X(x')dx'\,du\,du' \\ 
&=\iiint f_X(x'+u-u')f_{-Y}(u)f_{-Y}(u')f_X(x')dx'\,du\,du' \\ 
&=\iiint f_X(x'+u'-u)f_{-Y}(u)f_{-Y}(u')f_X(x')dx'\,du\,du' \\ 
&=I_{X,-Y} =\int f_{X-Y}(t)^2dt, 
\end{align}
by what was shown in the previous display.

Thus, 
$$\int f_{X+Y}(t)^2dt=\int f_{X-Y}(t)^2dt,$$
as desired.